# Every open set $ G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can be approximated by finite union of non-degenerate compact intervals contained in $G$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

For every open set $ G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $ \epsilon > 0 $ there exist a finite collection of compact intervals $\{ I_j \quad|\quad j=1,2,...m\}$ in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ such that $\cup^{j=1}_{m}I_j \subset G $ and  $ m(G\backslash \cup^{j=1}_{m}I_j)< \epsilon $ where m denotes lebesgue measure.

NOTE : compact interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $[a_1,b_1]\times[a_2,b_2]\times...\times[a_n, b_n]$ where $[a_i,b_i] $ are real closed intervals for each i.

**EDIT**: $m(G)$ is finite. sorry, I forget to write.

Comment: Obviously this is false. Take any open set with infinite measure.

Comment: sorry I forgot to write $m(G) $ is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the fact that every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a countable disjoint union of compact intervals. Indeed, if $G = \cup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$, then since $\sum_k m(I_k) = m(G) < \infty$, we may take $K$ so that $\sum_{k > K} m(I_k) < \epsilon$. Then $\cup_{k=1}^K I_k$ does the trick.

See page 7 for the proof of the first fact I stated

http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s8008.pdf

Comment: thank you for reference, sir. you forget to mention almost disjoint. @mathworker21

Comment: Ok. But it doesn't affect the proof, since the intersections have measure 0

Comment: thank you @mathworker21.

Comment: thank you, sir. please help me also with my previous question. Is that can be answered by the same proof. @mathworker21.

Answer (score -1):

This is false. For example take $G= \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: what about the case when the measure of G is finite @Fred