# For any $2-$d shape, can (at least) half its area be filled up with finitely many disjoint discs of the same size?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, area, geometric-topology, packing-problem

Here, the notation $B(x,r)$ means the ball with centre $x$ and radius $r$. So in $\mathbb{R}$ this represents an interval, in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ this represents a disc, etc. Whether the ball is open or closed shouldn't matter for this question, as the boundary of a ball doesn't affect its measure (length or area).

**Motivation**

[A quick recap](https://metaphor.ethz.ch/x/2023/hs/401-3601-00L/files/4-recap-topology.pdf):

In $\mathbb{R}$, every open set can be written as an at most countable union of disjoint open intervals.

However, it is NOT true that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, every open set can be written as an at most countable disjoint union of open
balls. For example, one can show that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\lbrace{(0, 0)\rbrace} $ is not a countable disjoint union of open balls.

---

Now if we let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an **open**, (possibly unbounded) set with finite, nonzero **length** (I believe *measure* is the technical term).

Then, $A$ is the union of at most countably many disjoint intervals: $ A= \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B(y_i,r_i).$ We have:$\text{ length(} A)= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \text{ length(} B(y_i,r_i)). $ Since the length is finite, this sum converges.
It is not difficult to show that there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k} \text{ length(} B(y_i,r_i)) > \frac{4}{5}\text{ length(} A).\ $ Then we can find very small $\varepsilon>0,$ and finitely many points $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^2,\ 1\leq i\leq n$ where $n\in\mathbb{N},$ such that the union of the disjoint intervals is a subset of $A$, that is,

$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B(x_i,\varepsilon) \subset A $$

and has length greater than half the length of $A.$

---

**Problem Statement**

> Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be an **open** (possibly unbounded) set with finite,
> nonzero **area**.
>
> Does there exist $\varepsilon>0$ and finitely many points
> $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^2,\ 1\leq i\leq n$ where $n\in\mathbb{N},$ such that
> the union of the disjoint discs is a subset of $A$, that is,
>
> $$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{n} B(x_i,\varepsilon) \subset A $$
>
> and has area greater than half the area of $A?$

I think this is either true by looking at $A\cup \mathbb{Q},$ or there is some fractal-like counter-example.

Note that the [packing of circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing#Densest_packing) in the obvious way (hexagonal lattice) has density $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}} \approx 0.9069.$

Comment: You need some condition on $A$ that it not have holes.  Otherwise, $A$ could be the unit square less all the points with both coordinates rational.  It does not contain any discs but has area $1$.

Comment: @RossMillikan good point. I have edited the question to say that $A$ must be an open set.

Answer (score 1):

Any open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an union of countably many almost disjoint cubes.
(see pag 7 of http://assets.press.princeton.edu/chapters/s8008.pdf). As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840303/every-open-set-g-subset-mathbbrn-can-be-approximated-by-finite-union-of/2840316#2840316) this implies that any open set $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite Lebesgue measure (i.e. Area) can be approximated by a finite number of almost disjoint cubes  $C_i$ such that
$$
m(G / \bigcup_i^N C_i)< \epsilon
$$
These cubes can be chosen to have all the same side length $l$.
So it is enough to show that the theorem holds for squares of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now consider the iscribed circle $D_i$ of each square. Its area is given by $A=\frac{\pi}{4} l^2$ So you have that
$$
m(G) \ge m(\bigcup_i^N D_i)=\frac{\pi}{4} m(\bigcup_i^N C_i) \ge \frac{\pi}{4}\left(m(G)- \epsilon \right)
$$

By choosing $\epsilon$ small enough you can make the area bigger than half of the area of $G$